# Random numbers across different programming languages

Tags: random

If I use the Random number generator function in different programming languages and I chose the same seed .. Do they have to give me the same random numbers ?

for example I used Java and Perl ... gave different numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless the two languages happen to use the same algorithm.

Comment: I think even different implementations of the same language may yield different results.

Comment: @S.C.: Depending on the language and its spec.

Comment: ..or the same Operating System API call.

Comment: @T.E.D.:  Unless the OS changes its algorithm, or you switch to a different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add, there is no such thing as 'random' in computer science.

Random number generation depends on the mathematical function used to generate the number. 
For example, Java uses 'Linear Congruential generator'.

If two programming languages use exact same function, theoretically they should give same 'random' number.

If you are interested more on how random numbers are generated, There is a good publication, The Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth.