# C's stdlib rand() function in Java

Tags: java, c, random, std

I've generated a series of random numbers from a known seed in C using `srand()` and `rand()` from stdlib. I now need to generate the same series of numbers using the same seed from C in Java.

Java's `Random` class documentation states it uses a "linear congruential formula". The documentation I've found on `rand()` says it uses a "linear congruential" generator, although I'm not sure if this is for one specific implementation.

Does anyone know if both generators will produce the same numbers if given the same seed or if a port of `srand()` and `rand()` exists for Java?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the C doesn't define the implementation of `rand`

Comment: @asaelr: I've seen "linear congruential" generator for `rand()` and "linear congruential formula" for `Random`, but I don't know if there are specific details that cause different numbers to be generated.

Comment: You know, it wouldn't be too terribly difficult to take (e.g.) the [GLIBC `random()` function](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/random/) and implement it in both your C and Java programs (provided the license is amenable to your needs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard does not dictate the implementations of srand() and rand().  As such, different environments (OS, C libraries, architecture, etc.) will more than likely produce sequences of numbers that are different for the same seed value.

Also, the implementation Java's Random class is not bound to any particular algorithm.  Here again, different JVMs may very well produce different sequences for the same seed value.  In addition, the implementation will more than likely not be tied to the standard C functions.  Which means, the Java produced sequence will be different than a C sequence using the same seed.

If you truly need to generate random sequence in Java to match exactly that of the standard C functions, the best you could hope to do is replicate the sequence for a particular environment.  This would require creating a JNI library to proxy calls to srand() and rand() or creating some other external process that makes the calls and is invoked from Java.  Either way, that's a lot of complexity and more program maintenance.

If in fact all you need are random sequences that appear to be uniformly distributed, regardless of the exact values, then use Random as is.  It is more than sufficient for most RNG needs.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know. It looks like I will implement my own random number generator so I can be more in control.

Comment: You may have a better bet replicating Java's `Random` behavior in C, since `java.util.Random` specifies its algorithm, and it's a well-tested PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

As said in other answer, the C standard doesn't even specify that `rand()` will return the same sequence across different C platforms (libraries), and likewise nothing in Java guarantees that it matches any given C (or other Java) implementation. You could use JNI to call the specific C implementation on that platform, but this would only guarantee the same sequence to be produced when both the C and Java programs are run on the same platform using the same C library.

If you wish to ensure the same sequence in all situations, you need to implement the same random number generator in both languages. A simple example can be found in POSIX.1-2001, and is quoted on many `man 3 rand` pages:

```
static unsigned long next = 1;

/* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}

void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

It is trivially portable to Java. The quality of randomness produced this generator is not very high, but it's not really guaranteed to be any better with `rand()` either, so you would need to implement something fancier if better randomness is required.

Answer (score 0):

In both C and Java, the same seed will generate the same random values. While the underlying mechanism might be different, this property is maintained in every programming language I know about.

C and Java will probably not generate the *same* set of random numbers given a seed. The only property that is maintained is that given a seed, a programming language will generate the same random numbers.

Comment: this seems to contradict the response given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045579/random-numbers-across-different-programming-languages

Comment: I think the OP is asking if C and Java will generate the _same_ random numbers.  That is, the C and the Java have the same output.

Comment: Given a seed, two programming language will probably generate a different set of numbers, but it will always generate the same set of numbers for a given seed.

Comment: Edited to be more clear; two programming languages will not generate the same set of random numbers. The same seed will generate the same set of random numbers only within a programming language.

Comment: @Oleski By no means is that a certainty.  Two versions of the standard C library, GNU and Microsoft for instance, can very well produce different sequences for the same seed value.  As asaelr stated, the C standard does not mandate a particular algorithm.  This is relegated to any particular C library distribution and they can be different.